# How can I sort a LinkedList based on the last names without using an sort methods such as Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting

I have a LinkedList called recordInformation that contains an object at each index. The object  consists of a first name, last name, numnbr, and balance separated by spaces. So recordInformation looks like
 [[firstName lastName number balance][fname lastname number bal]]. 
Everytime I add a record to recordInformation, I sort the list based on last name. I've attempted to write a method, but when I output the list in another method, the indexes have not changed. Is compareTo the correct way to check for alphabetical order?

```
public void sortRecords(LinkedList list){
    if (list.size()==1)
        return;

    Object obj = recordInformation.getLast();
    String sortVar = obj.toString();
    String[] varArray = sortVar.split(" ");

    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        Object obj1 = recordInformation.get(i);
        String compare = obj1.toString();
        String[] compareArray = compare.split(" ");
        //varArray[1] and compareArray[1] hold the last names
        if ((varArray[1].compareTo(compareArray[1]))<0){
            recordInformation.add(i,obj);
            recordInformation.remove(list.size()-1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you use Collections.Sort()?

Comment: This is not a sort method, it might be an attempt at a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), but not a very good one. Maybe read up on [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). And maybe [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) too.

Comment: One more thing, you are using index based iteration on a `LinkedList` - this is **very** ill advised. Index based iteration on a `LinkedList` is an O(n^2) operation. Either use an `Iterator` or use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I have to use LinkedList though. I'll try the Iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain sorted order and at the same time do a lot if insertions then `LinkedList` is one of the last datastructures to use.

What you are after is [Red-Black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) tree. In java it's implemented as `java.util.TreeMap` class

Comment: i wish i had a choice. LinkedList is required

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the list since the beginning, why don't you insert the element in the correct place?

I mean if there is A, and you need to put C, then put A->C, if a B comes then put A->B->C.
That way you won't use Collections.sort (or any sort).

Comment: sounds good but there a method in the program if the user wants to change there last name. and when that method runs, the list needs to be sorted again. no worries though. i corrected the method

Comment: One O(n)  sort,  insertion sort,  uses this idea.  Create an empty list,  then iterate through the original list,  inserting each element into the proper place in the new list.  The new list will be sorted when finished.